# plotly scatter with x =df2.index .values, y = df2.coulmn.values

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a dataset which is a time series which consist of sold item and how much sold on each date. i am using the following code for plotly scatter after transpose. i have defined `x =df.index.values, y = df.coulmn.values` for scatter but i get a blank graph. 
I am not getting error either need your expert guidance to fix the same.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.offline as pyo

df2 =df1[ df1['Country']== 'Pen'].groupby(['Pen']).sum()

df2= df2.transpose()

trace = go.Scatter(
x= [dict(values=list(df2.index))],
y= [dict(values=list(df2.columns))],mode='lines')
layout = go.Layout( title='Sold item count')
data= [trace]

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

pyo.plot(fig)
```

even i tried  with `x =df2.index.values, y = df2.coulmn.values` still the same.

Comment: Please, provide the dataframe in a usable format. Thanks.

Comment: there was issue with the date format  after changing the date format issue fixed @sentence

Comment: Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the date format with few data in dataset `pd.to_datetime` helped to resolve the issue.